# Почему строка имеет значение Null

Tags: c#, null

Есть некий класс с конструктором

```
public class Neuron
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string rusname { get; set; }
    public float[,] weight { get; set; }
    public float sum {get;set;}

    public Neuron(string name,string rusname)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.rusname = rusname;
        weight = new float[7, 7];
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

В другом классе я создаю объекты

```
neurons[0] = new Neuron("Zero", "Ноль");
neurons[1] = new Neuron("One", "Один");
neurons[2] = new Neuron("Two", "Два");
neurons[3] = new Neuron("Three", "Три");
neurons[4] = new Neuron("Four", "Четыре");
neurons[5] = new Neuron("Five", "Пять");
neurons[6] = new Neuron("Six", "Шесть");
neurons[7] = new Neuron("Seven", "Семь");
neurons[8] = new Neuron("Eight", "Восемь");
neurons[9] = new Neuron("Nine","Девять");
```

В конце работы программы я пытаюсь вывести имена объекта

```
string str = neurons[9].name;
string str1 = neurons[9].rusname;
```

При этом первая строка имеет значение и проблем с выводом нет, а значение второй - null. По какой причине?

Метод вывода имен:

```
public void screen_info()
{
    terminal.Clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < neurons.Length; i++)
    {
        terminal.Text += neurons[i].name + ": " + neurons[i].sum + Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine;
    }
    string str = neurons[9].name;
    string str1 = neurons[9].rusname;
    terminal.Text += str + "  " + str1;
}
```

Нашёл участок кода, после которого значение второго имени становится null

```
 if (File.Exists("weights.txt"))
        {
            using(FileStream file = new FileStream("weights.txt", FileMode.Open))
            {
                neurons = (Neuron[]) upload_saves.Deserialize(file);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53073/discussion-on-question-by-zoom-smash-----null).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public string name { get; set; }
> public string rusname { get; set; }
> public float[,] weight { get; set; }
> public float sum {get;set;}
> ```

Чтобы значение не менялось нигде кроме конструктора, надо это заменить на

```
public string name { get; }
public string rusname { get; }
public float[,] weight { get; }
public float sum { get; }
```

> ```
> public Neuron(string name,string rusname)
> {
>     this.name = name;
>     this.rusname = rusname;
> ```

А здесь надо убедиться, что в имени аргумента нет опечатки. Лучше взять имя свойства и скопипастить его во все 3 места.

Comment: Нет, не помогает, посмотрите, я добавил код

Comment: У sum, тогда уж приватный сет тож поставить надо :)

Comment: @Grundy, не понял.

Comment: @Qwertiy, о! я не туда посмотрел оказывается :-) но сейчас вроде бы sum можно только один раз присвоить в конструкторе? а он там что-то подсчитывать хотел в нем :)

Comment: @Grundy, ну баг исправит, потом посчитает)

Comment: @Grundy с суммой проблем нет, нейронка в остальном нормально работает)